# Message Delivery Failure

Tags: email, plesk

I got this bounce back.  What does it mean and How do I solve it? Thanks.

```
MailEnable: Message Delivery Failure.
Reason: ME-E0193: [B7C2FA717C634859B59BCACF7D8C38A8.MAI] Message Delivery Failure.

Your message addressed to the target domain could not be delivered because
the mail server responsible for this domain returned a permanent error.

The server returned: 554 5.7.1 Delivery not authorized
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that a spam filter blocked the mail.

Try to send the same mail from a email webservice and see if you encounter the same error.

Comment: No reverse DNS record exists in my domain. How should I fix it?

Comment: Contact your ISP  and they will set you up with a valid PTR record